# Is there a one-on-one replacement for Kendo DataSource?

Tags: kendo-datasource, kendo-ui-angular2

The Kendo UI for jQuery library had an easy to configure DataSource, that could be used to wrap around a REST API.

Is there something similar (planned to be) in Kendo UI for Angular2? Or is the recommended way to use services that wrap around `@angular/http`, and use RxJS `Observable`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, they consider Angular2 to have sufficient functionality, so your last supposition is correct.

> I'm afraid that we do not plan to have a DataSource component. We
>   believe that having a DataSource like the one in Kendo UI for jQuery
>   does not fit in the NG2 context. The framework already provides most
>   of the DataSource functionality such as ability to fetch data, change
>   tracking etc. Also there are pleiad of libraries and patterns for
>   working with data. Thus, having single component to handle all of
>   those seems more of a unnecessary constraint.
>
> However, we do plan to make available helper functions in order to
>   streamline the Grid data operation descriptors serialization and
>   operation handling. Providing better flexibility and integration with
>   the rest of the NG2 ecosystem. Some functions already exist for
>   [sorting and paging](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/) for OData. As well as generating a comparer
>   function for in-memory processing (this is demonstrated in [this sample](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#sorting)).

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/45